# Sort values in a Pandas DataFrame using the python sort function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataset where I am trying to sort the row value in each column, but have not been able to find an efficient way of performing the operation. I was hoping someone would be able to point me in a more optimized way of sorting:

`|Column_to_Sort|Desired_Output|
 | a, x, z,c    | a, c, x, z   |
 | ball, apple  | apple, ball  |`

Essentially, I am trying to rearrange the list of items in the `Column_to_sort` alphabetically and separated by a comma.

I wrote the following code to perform the operation, however I don't believe it is the best way of performing the operation:

```
 def sort_val(x):
    String_ = x.split(",")
    String_.sort()
    return (String_)

df['Desired_Output'] = df['Column_to_Sort'].apply(lambda x: sort_val(x))
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me .

Comment: ah perfect, for some reason I ran it on my machine twice and it was exceptionally slow. Just tried it again and no issues. I should have waited before posting the question. Sorry about that

Comment: Is it possible to close the question?

Comment: @Raptor776 you can always delete your question if you choose to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution by use `dot` and `get_dummies`

```
s=df['Column_to_Sort'].str.get_dummies(', ').sort_index(axis=1)
s.dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1]
Out[547]: 
0       a,c,x,z
1    apple,ball
dtype: object
```